# AzureRmApiManagementContext: FormatException when used as parameter in cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-api-management

I am trying to use some of the Azure Powershell cmdlets in the `AzureRM.ApiManagement` module. A lot of the cmdlets require a `context` parameter, which is `PsApiManagementContext` object.

Following the [guidance](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell/blob/master/azureps-cmdlets-docs/ResourceManager/AzureRM.ApiManagement/v3.5.0/New-AzureRmApiManagementContext.md) I have created a context using the `New-AzureRmApiManagementContext` cmdlet:

```
$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext 
                    -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" 
                    -ServiceName "MyApimService"
```

I then pass the context as a parameter to the cmdlet:

`Get-AzureRmApiManagementUser -Context $ApiMgmtContext`

The problem is that I get an error back as follows:

`Get-AzureRmApiManagementUser : FormatException: One more parameters were not formatted correctly`

I have used Fiddler to inspect the request that it generates and I can see that the body of the request is empty, so there must be something wrong with the way the context object has been created, even though I have basically copied the example in the microsoft docs. I have logged into my Azure subscription using `Login-AzureRmAccount` and selected the correct subscription prior to trying to create the context.

What am I doing wrong in the creation of the context object?

Comment: If you add `-ErrorVariable error_message` to your command? When you then printout a message from $error_message do you get anything?

Comment: Yes I get `FormatException: One more parameters were not formatted correctly`, the same message as stated above

Comment: Can you set `$DebugPreference="Continue"` on the powershell prompt and open an issue on the page https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/new and provide the output of the cmdline.

Comment: Just one thing that occurred to me, do you have line breaks in your script like you have above?  If yes, you should add ` char to the end of each line to split it correctly: `$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext \`
                    -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" \`
                    -ServiceName "MyApimService"`

Comment: @DeclanMcNulty please check your Azure powershell version, my Azure powershell version is 3.7.0, and `Get-AzureRmApiManagementUser -Context $ApiMgmtContext` works fine. please run this command to check Azure PowerShell version `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`.

Comment: @DeclanMcNulty did you manage to resolve your problem? I have got the exact same error, from the same API, but I'm hitting the REST API's directly.